# When does `@static` run?

Tags: julia, precompile

`@static expr` is a way to only run `expr` once;
for some sense of once.
but what sense of once is it?

Is it:

- once per time the package is installed?
- once per time the package is loaded?
- some other definition

The most common use is for OS checking: e.g.
`ccall((@static Sys.iswindows() ? :_fopen : :fopen), ...)`

I am wondering if I can use it to generate different code based on an environment variable: In particular `JULIA_NUM_THREADS`.
This environment variable can change between runs of julia,
but if it changes during the session nothing will react to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is run at parse time (technically it is run just after parse time, when macros are expanded). If used in a package with precompilation enabled (the default), then it will be evaluated the first time it is loaded (i.e. when you see the message "INFO: Precompiling module ...").

So no, you can't use it to generate different code based on environmental variables, unless you explicitly use [`__precompile__(false)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.__precompile__) outside the module (however then you will have longer loading times).